# How to detect current language and use JS to present dynamic content in Docusaurus pages

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, docusaurus

I am using Docusaurus to build a site with two language - `en` and `zh`.

What I want is a dynamic `if-else` in JS:

```py
if current_language is en:
    title = "en title"
else:
    title = "zh title"
```

How can I achieve this in Docusaurus pages? The default i18n is not handy to translate long HTML...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`useDocusaurusContext`](https://docusaurus.io/docs/docusaurus-core#useDocusaurusContext) to get the current locale:

```js
import useDocusaurusContext from '@docusaurus/useDocusaurusContext';

const { siteConfig, i18n } = useDocusaurusContext();
console.log(i18n.currentLocale); // e.g. 'en'
```